# How to get value of cells from DataTable

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datatable

i got a select query that returns one row.
here is my DAL function:

```
public Test.RequestsDataTable getRequestById2(int rid)
{
    RequestsTableAdapter adapter2 = new RequestsTableAdapter();
    Test.RequestsDataTable dt2 = adapter2.GetData(rid);
    return (dt2);
}
```

Test.xsd is tableAdapter.

my question is how do i call it from code behind file and get each cell value and store it in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It's a method. Call it.

It returns a `Test.RequestsDataTable`. If your table has columns `Column1` and `Column2`, then you can do:

```
var dt = getRequestById2(123);
string col1 = dt.Column1;
int col2 = dt.Column2;
```

If that doesn't answer your question, then you need to be more clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote it in cs file:

Test.RequestsDataTable rdt = new DalObj().getRequestById2(111);

rdt.Columns[0] -> returns DataColumn so i defined

DataColumn c1 = rdt.Columns[0];

but i get the column name and not it's value.